# How does one query the resolver name of a DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nslookup, dig

The [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io/) search tool, for some DNS servers, shows a `Resolver name` value for what it finds on UDP port 53. For example, [80.82.117.140](https://www.shodan.io/host/80.82.117.140) shows `Resolver name: server402.xenserve.com` and [103.81.27.118](https://www.shodan.io/host/103.81.27.118#53) reports `Resolver name: smartway-h7`.

I have searched the web as well as the man pages for `dig` and `nslookup`, as well as searching the output of `dig @ip_of_dns_server`, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve the resolver name for a DNS server.

How can I query the resolver name myself using Linux command-line tools?

Comment: PTR record on the IP shows `ns1.402.xenserve.com.` as name. But how is this useful in any way? When clients configure DNS servers they obviously put their IP, not their names, otherwise there is a circular loop.

Comment: Thank you. However, this doesn't explain where Shodan gets `server402.xenserve.com`. I'm trying to figure out how to configure and verify the resolver name in BIND9 for my own server, since--useful or not--it is apparently publicly visible.

Comment: `server402.xenserve.com` does also resolve to same IP, so if someone maintains a database of forward queries results, after some time to learn data, a reverse can be found by just poking in it. Or the `PTR` record changed "recently".

Comment: I added an example above where the resolver name is not even a valid domain.

Comment: `dig -x 103.81.27.118` returns NXDOMAIN from APnic, so whatever name you get comes from "elsewhere" and not the DNS (but there is also no guarantee that a PTR record follows guidelines for a name, nor that that name does in fact resolve, and resolve to the original IP address; for most uses `PTR` records are useless today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. It is part of the Chaos (CH) class DNS record. For the examples given above, these queries return the information I was looking for:

```
dig @80.82.117.140 hostname.bind TXT CHAOS +short
dig @103.81.27.118 hostname.bind TXT CHAOS +short
```

These commands display `"server402.xenserve.com"` and `"smartway-h7"` respectively, the exact values that Shodan displays as "Resolver name". This is normally the hostname of the DNS server.

See also:

- `dig @[server_IP] version.bind TXT CHAOS +short` - version of DNS server
- `dig @[server_IP] authors.bind TXT CHAOS +short` - list of server authors
- `dig @[server_IP] id.server TXT CHAOS +short` - DNS server ID
- [What Linux command line tool can I use to determine the version and name of a remote DNS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1350517/what-linux-command-line-tool-can-i-use-to-determine-the-version-and-name-of-a-re)
- [BIND documentation - configuration reference](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#built-in-server-information-zones)